# Is there a poster image fallback for html5 video element using new formats?

Tags: html, image, html5-video

```
 <video poster="images/transparent.webp">
    <source src="assets/video.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

Is there any fallback method for video element poster images that use **webp** or **avif** formats (instead of jpg or png) for browsers that don't support them?

Comment: Nope so you'll have engineer your own solution. If this was my problem I would use JS to create an `img` element dynamically and give it a small webp/avif file then **listen** for errors. If you get a decode error (during image loading) then the format is not supported, so use JS to replace the poster image link (your video tag needs an ID for JS to control it), Assuming your ID is `myVid` so the example pseudo-code would be `if (error == true) { myVid.poster="someJPG"; } else { myVid.poster = "someWEBP"; }`

Comment: PS: If you can make `.isSupported` work for your task then it'll be easiest way. Try this first if possible.